# Simple Commerce for Downloadable Products

Tags: structure, transcribe, simple-commerce

I am just wondering if anyone has ever used EE's Simple Commerce for a store that requires items to be downloaded (music songs and albums in my case)? And if so is there anything I should watch out for.

I'm using ee 2.7.1, Structure and Transcribe.

Thanks.
Stephen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue you're going to run into is that Simple Commerce doesn't have any tags for displaying purchase information, so you'll have no way to verify if the user has purchased the content, thus allowing them to download the product.

If you have any knowledge of SQL queries, you could possibly use the [Active Record](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) module to directly grab purchase info from the database. If you don't know any SQL, [this is an excellent tutorial](http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/mysql-and-expressionengine/).